# Pandas sum over duplicated indices with sum

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, duplicates

I have a data frame indexed by date

```
transactions_ind
Out[25]: 
                   Ticker     Transaction  Number_of_units      Price
Date                                                                 
2012-10-11  ROG VX Equity             Buy            12000  182.00000
2012-10-16  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -5000  184.70000
2012-11-16  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -5000  175.51580
2012-12-07  ROG VX Equity             Buy             5000  184.90000
2012-12-11  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -3000  188.50000
2012-12-11  ROG VX Equity  Reversal: Sell             3000  188.50000
2012-12-11  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -3000  188.50000
2012-12-11  ROG VX Equity  Reversal: Sell             3000  188.50000
2012-12-11  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -3000  188.50000
2012-12-20  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -5000  185.80000
```

I want to sum over the duplicated index values (2012-12-11) but only over the column "Number_of_units".

```
transactions_ind
Out[25]: 
                   Ticker     Transaction  Number_of_units      Price
Date                                                                 
2012-10-11  ROG VX Equity             Buy            12000  182.00000
2012-10-16  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -5000  184.70000
2012-11-16  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -5000  175.51580
2012-12-07  ROG VX Equity             Buy             5000  184.90000
2012-12-11  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -3000  188.50000
2012-12-20  ROG VX Equity            Sell            -5000  185.80000
```

Using

```
transactions_ind.groupby(transactions_ind.index).sum()
```

deletes the columns "Ticker" and "Transaction" since those are filled with non-numeric values. Also I would olike to know how to deal with the different strings in the "Transactions" column when I sum over the "Number_of_units" column. Hope there exists a one-liner in pandas. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.aggregate.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg({'Ticker': 'first',
                                'Transaction': 'first',
                                'Number_of_units':sum, 
                                'Price': 'first'})
#reorder columns
df = df[['Ticker','Transaction','Number_of_units','Price']]
print df
                   Ticker Transaction  Number_of_units     Price
Date                                                            
2012-10-11  ROG VX Equity         Buy            12000  182.0000
2012-10-16  ROG VX Equity        Sell            -5000  184.7000
2012-11-16  ROG VX Equity        Sell            -5000  175.5158
2012-12-07  ROG VX Equity         Buy             5000  184.9000
2012-12-11  ROG VX Equity        Sell            -3000  188.5000
2012-12-20  ROG VX Equity        Sell            -5000  185.8000
```

Comment: hi - just an FYI: to get this to work with `groupby.sum()` I had to use `df.index.names` as the argument to `groupby` (pandas 1.5.2)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works great if (like in your case) you only have a single index  column. If you have a MultiIndex, it will unfortunately reduce it to a tuple. This is how you can restore the MultiIndex:

```
import pandas as pd
index_names = df.index.names
df = df.groupby(df.index).agg({...})
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=index_names)
```